# Do I need three subpass dependencies for two subpasses?

Tags: vulkan

The first subpass dependency is src from external to the subpass 0, the second subpass dependency is from 0 to 1. Do I need another one for 1 to external? To sync with everything after the subpass?

Comment: You are the only one who can know what you need. Vulkan only mandates you must not cause any synchronization hazards.

Comment: @krOoze Generally speaking is there usually one more dependency than there are subpasses. Intuitively I'd say there would be, one for before the render pass to the first subpass, one for between each subpass and then one for between the last subpass and after the render pass. Is it valid to have two render passes and three subpass dependencies? How does Vulkan interpret these? All in a row sequentially?

Comment: Generally speaking the subpass dependency DAG between subpasses and external dependencies as well as any other sync primitives (all of which you provide) matches the data dependencies in **your** code (which you haven't shared). It is valid to have zero Subpass Dependencies. As long as that doesn't make your code missynchronized.

Comment: @krOoze I think I'd prefer to sync with outside the render pass manually. If the situation calls for different synchronisation requirements, isn't it better to decide whether to manually place a barrier instead of getting a different render pass?